# Have I missed End 1 by going to Sheol?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I killed Mom's Heart recently but instead of jumping into the chest, I went through the Devil Room into Sheol. After killing Mom's Heart a few more times in different runs I've noticed that 'End 1' is blocked out in the 'Stats' menu (but not End 2 / End 3 etc.). Is this a glitch / is there any way to force the ending?

Comment: I was able to unlock several endings (2-4 I think) by skipping the chest and going through devil/angel rooms.  However, I don't think End 1 was one of them.

Comment: Incidentally, you can view unlocked endings from the same stats menu you see it blocked out in.

Answer (score 6):

It's most likely a bug.

My best guess is that the devs didn't expect someone to actually skip the big yellow chest and just didn't build any safeguard in for that.

The only thing to do would be to mail (for support):

- isaac[AT]nicalis.com
- info[AT]nicalis.com
- Or go to the [Binding of Isaac Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/) and make a post there.

Make sure to also give them a screenshot of your problem and hopefully they will patch it.

Alternatively.. You'll have to start over again.

Comment: Thanks for this. Already posted in the Reddit, and looks like I'm not the only one (various endings missed due to going to Sheol).

Comment: Nah, I'm sure they expected it: I beat Sheol on most of my first 10 heart kills, and each time the appropriate womb ending unlocked.

Comment: Fair enough, wonder what oddness is going on. Now reticent to skip the chest when the Sheol door opens... (not that it does that much for me!)

Comment: This seems to have fixed itself - not sure if it was update 1.0.1 or if it's because I've progressed further to End 13, but now all endings appear.